# What's the Python equivalent of the Ruby class Net:HTTP?

Tags: python, ruby

A co-worker wrote some code using the `Net:HTTP` class from the `net/https` module. He also uses the `URI` class from the `uri` module. What modules would have equivalent classes and functionality in Python? I did some googling and found [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) and [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html). Would these two Python modules be the equivalent ones?

Comment: Do you expect a 1:1 compatiblity between Ruby and Python modules? What functionality do you need exactly?...weird question

Comment: @Maulwurfn I was just wondering if there is some other module that I missed finding that provides similar functionality. Of course I don't expect 1:1 compatibility between the Ruby and Python modules.

Comment: Ask a specific question "How do fetch a URL in Python" instead of which of my 100 methods in Ruby module X match with Python module Y...this generic question is pointless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: the question is pointless. Every module has lots of functionality. You need to decide what you really need.

Second: use the 'requests' module for Python:

http://python-requests.org/

It's the most Pythonic module for dealing with requests.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby

```
require 'net/http'

url = 'http://www.acme.com/products/3322' # ACME boomerang
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))

resp_text = resp.body
```

Python

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.acme.com/products/3322'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Comment: State of the art retrieving an URL is using the 'requests' module